# Is there a way to spoof rooted android's light sensor values

Tags: android, android-sensors, spoofing, light-sensor

Since Samsungs, note 4 in particular have an ultra bright screen mode (750nits) that automatically activates when the device is exposed to direct sun light I am wondering if in some way I can change the reading of the light sensor so I trick it into that mode whenever I want.

If possible at all, talking about rooted Android.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Xposed is required and https://github.com/wardellchandler/disableproxsensor this app or your own implementation of xposed's magic.